# SQL Server: retrieving the first word before the space or line break

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data set.

```
incidentid      calltype
----------      ---------
_1700528604     101A1 (Investigation)
_1700528605
_1700528606     304B2
                Problem
```

As it is shown, the calltype data for _1700528606 has Problem in the next line. I need to retrieve the first word from each callType, so that the end result will look like:

```
 incidentid      calltype
----------      ---------
_1700528604     101A1 
_1700528605
_1700528606     304B2
```

I used the partindex() as below.

```
select patindex( ('%[' + char(10) + ' ]%'), calltype)
from #DispatchCallType 
where IncidentId in (
'_1700528604',
'_1700528605',
'_1700528606'
)
```

The result was:

```
6
0
8
```

So I ran the following query.

```
SELECT incidentid,
 CASE 
  WHEN patindex( ('%[' + char(10) + ' ]%'), calltype) > 0
  THEN LEFT(callType, charindex(' ', callType) - 1)
 ELSE callType 
 END AS callType
from #DispatchCallType 
where IncidentId in (
'_1700528604',
'_1700528605',
'_1700528606'
)
```

The above query returns data like this.

```
incidentid      calltype
----------      ---------
_1700528604     101A1 (Investigation)
_1700528605
_1700528606     304B2
```

Comment: Apparently what looks like a space is not `char(10)`.

Comment: If your "words" (`'101A1'` isn't a word) only contain alphanumerical characters, you could use `PATINDEX` instead.

Comment: @larnu - tried using the partindex, but still not quite there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "words" only contain alphanumerics, then you can use `PATINDEX`:

```
LEFT(calltype, PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-z]%',calltype))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look for either, you could use `patindex()`:

```
patindex( '%[', char(10) + ' ]%', calltype)
```

Comment: I tried using the partindex(), but still not getting the right result...